# How does JPA determine which class is calling a method?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm working on a class that will be subclassed by a number of different clases. There's a few static methods that need to know the name of the subclass that the call is originating from.  Now I know I can do something like this in the static method

```
foo(Class clazz, String things, String... stuff){}
```

but I would prefer to make it easier on the user and not have to make a call such as

```
Pass.retract(Pass.class, xxxx, yyyy);
```

instead I'd prefer it to look like

```
Pass.retract(xxxx, yyyy);
```

Now, I know that JPA does this with it's find() function. I've stepped through the search functions many times but it seems as if the entity variables are magically populated. How does it do this? If any gurus out there have an idea I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: why don't you add the "convenient" util methods to the subclasses?

Comment: If you have a method with logic in it that is specific to its callers, that means that some of the logic of the callers is in this method.  It is practically never a good idea to put logic specific to one class in the method of another class -- there are other ways to share code.  I suggest you back up and consider why your design calls for this construct, and determine how to get rid of it.  JPA is doing it for a completely different purpose, one for which these basic rules of procedural logic don't apply.

Comment: The logic isn't different. Simply the strings that are set change. Essentially doing what JPA does but for various file structures. Each of the subclasses do many of their own things, but there is a small amount of shared functionality that would be repeated verbatim aside from the class name. I'm trying to do this as a courtesy to the other programmers implementing.

Answer (score 2):

Play 1.x does a lot of the magic, including the find methods by using [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist/). It is a runtime byte code enhancer that can hide away complexity of APIs from your users by doing some 'magic'.

That said, Play2 opted to move away from this approach, as the core devs felt that the magic was too difficult to understand when people were trying to maintain the core code base.

Comment: I'm still using Play 1.2.x so I'm not completely aware how 2.x works. Could you elaborate at all?

Comment: Play 2 does not do any magic. It uses specific design patterns to follow.